# Why is the $ alias not working for this jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#customdivid').prepend($('<div class="myclass"></div>'));    
})(jQuery);
```

I'm using Wordpress, and I understand that it runs in no conflict mode, but I thought if I wrote a function out as above I would be able to use $ instead of jQuery.

Script runs fine when I just use jQuery, but I want to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Update: I guess what I'm really asking is how can I create this in a js file. jQuery = $

Would I just do `var $ = jQuery`

I read somewhere that I can include `$` in the `()` after function and end the function with jQuery and all would be fine, hence my example above.

Hope I'm making sense

Thanks again!

Comment: We're gonna need a little more info than that, friend. Is there anything you can add?

Comment: like? It's just the structure of a function with filler stuff. Not sure what else could be needed for the question I am asking

Comment: Like additional context. It's often hard to diagnose issues with a simple copy paste of jQuery. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing two different things. An IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression):

```
(function($){
  // $ is jQuery
}(jQuery));
```

With a ready event:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  // now you can use $
});
```

If you simply pass a function to jQuery it's the same as the ready event:

```
jQuery(function($){
  // use $
});
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks! I'll accept answer in when it lets me